# Converting string to int (C++)

Tags: c++, string, int, atoi

I looked everywhere and can't find an answer to this specific question :(

I have a string date, which contains the date with all the special characters stripped away. (i.e : yyyymmddhhmm or 201212031204).

I'm trying to convert this string into an int to be able to sort them later. I tried atoi, did not work because the value is too high for the function. I tried streams, but it always returns -858993460 and I suspect this is because the string is too large too. I tried atol and atoll and they still dont give the right answer.

I'd rather not use boost since this is for a homework, I dont think i'd be allowed.

Am I out of options to convert a large string to an int ?
Thank you!

What i'd like to be able to do :

```
int dateToInt(string date)
{
date = date.substr(6,4) + date.substr(3,2) + date.substr(0,2) + date.substr(11,2) + date.substr(14,2);
int d;
d = atoi(date.c_str());
return d;

}
```

Comment: If your only need is to sort them, sort them as strings.

Comment: Why don't you return it in date/time struct? There's no way to store that many digits in an int, so some larger data type is necessary; using the same form as system time functions seems appropriate (`date_t` iirc)

Comment: Do you have any 64-bit variable data types available to you? Your resulting number is over 201 billion which is far too large for a 32-bit integer to hold. The maximum for an unsigned 32-bit integer is 4,294,967,295.

Comment: @peachykeen, you're right, it seems like it'd make more sense to use a date/time struct for that. I'm just a little confused about how I'd be able to sort these structs after..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track that the value is too large, but it's not just for those functions. It's too large for an `int` in general. `int`s only hold up to 32 bits, or a maximum value of 2147483647 (4294967295 if unsigned). A `long long` is guaranteed to be large enough for the numbers you're using. If you happen to be on a 64-bit system, a `long` will be too.

Now, if you use one of these larger integers, a stream should convert properly. Or, if you want to use a function to do it, have a look at `atoll` for a `long long` or `atol` for a `long`. (Although for better error checking, you should really consider `strtoll` or `strtol`.)

Completely alternatively, you could also use a `time_t`. They're integer types under the hood, so you can compare and sort them. And there's some nice functions for them in `<ctime>` (have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/).

Comment: And also you can define compare(void *,void*) and use sort(a,compare) avalible in cstdlib

Answer (score 5):

You get negative numbers because  `201212031204` is too large to fit `int`. Consider using `long long`s

BTW, You may sort strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef long long S64;

S64 dateToInt(char * s) {
    S64 retval = 0;
    while (*s) {
         retval = retval * 10 + (*s - '0');
         ++s;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Note that as has been stated, the numbers you're working with will not fit into 32 bits.

Comment: You need to increment s. The loop never ends